# How to size header image for mobile device

Tags: css, image, mobile, web

I am looking to properly size my header image so that when viewed in a mobile device such as my Iphone it fits the screen.

The website address is www.maxim-industries.com

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. If someone can show me the correct css I will add it to my notebook for future reference.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: What's the header image? the big tractor?

Comment: Yes, the large white vehicle towards the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Chris,

Use the @media rule so that the website adjusts based on different devices and sizes.
Use min-device-width and max-device-width as well as height to narrow down more specifically. Of course you need to look at how the different models of iPhone's are sized as well.

[Apple - iPhone Compare](https://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/)

Additionally, you would have to size your image down as necessary within the @media rule. Judging by the fact that you're using SquareSpace there is probably a panel somewhere in the ADMIN section where you can change the stylesheets.

Please note next time that your question is likely to get flagged and downvoted when it appears that you haven't done the research or documented your attempts at making this work. Here's the infamous link for that -- I've gone through the same process too.[How to Ask Good Questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have all sorts of unnecessary markup. all that aside, you should only have to give the image `width: 100%;`. But due to other components on your site. this didn't work as it should -- margins and paddings, etc.

```
#siteWrapper {
   padding-top: 95px;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
#siteWrapper {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.header-inner {
    padding: 5px 0;
    display: block
  }
}
#5330ee6ae4b05a2fa30d68c6 {
display: none;
}

.banner-thumbnail-wrapper has-description {
  padding: 0;
}
#thubnail {
  position: relative;
}
#thumbnail img {
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
/*left: 0;*/
}
.transparent-header.view-list .banner-thumbnail-wrapper, .transparent-header.collection-type-page .banner-thumbnail-wrapper {
/* padding: 180px 0 155px; GET RID*/ 
/* min-height: 0; GET RID */

}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
content: " ";
display: table;
height: 0px;
}
```